# Beginner in iphone ,Making a pdf,what am i doing wrong

Tags: iphone, pdf

I am making a pdf app in which i get problem

```
    // make  pdf
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,    NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    BOOL isFileCreated;

    if(isPortrait)
    {
        isFileCreated = UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/test.pdf",documentsDirectory],CGRectMake(self.m_ScrollView.frame.origin.x, self.m_ScrollView.frame.origin.y-340, self.m_ScrollView.frame.size.width, self.m_ScrollView.contentSize.height), nil); 

    }
    else
    {
        isFileCreated = UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/test.pdf",documentsDirectory],CGRectMake(self.m_ScrollView.frame.origin.x, self.m_ScrollView.frame.origin.y-250, self.m_ScrollView.frame.size.width, self.m_ScrollView.contentSize.height), nil); 
    }

    if(isFileCreated)
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
        [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
    }
```

this code creates only half pdf. which currently shows on the screen and rest of the pdf is missing which is currently not shown on screen.what should i do?
thanks in advance.

Comment: here am using UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() method. i think it renders only currently showing area. is there any way to render all the area of view.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/16552-pdf-viewer-tutorial.html

or

[iOS SDK - Programmatically generate a PDF file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362734/ios-sdk-programmatically-generate-a-pdf-file)