# Can I use JPEG compression for images in pdf files generated on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, pdf

Currently I am dealing with the problem that I have pdf file with lots of 1024x768 images in it and am trying to optimize the pdf's file size, but the only solution that I thought is good enough for now is compressing the images with jpeg compression. The problem is that I did not find any way to do that with iOS APIs. Am I missing something, is there a way?
I`m welcome to suggestions on how to optimize the pdf with other means (lowering the resolution of the images is not a good solution for me).

**Edit:** If someone knows another API to use for pdf generation on iOS - links would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there isn't any out of the box solution for optimizing a pdf with iOS apis, sry!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362734/ios-sdk-programmatically-generate-a-pdf-file

Comment: http://blog.nitropdf.com/2008/02/5-tricks-to-shrinkreduce-pdf-file-size/ just to understand the ways you can reduce pdf file size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is interested I found a solution to my problem by using a free pdf library - libHaru. It gave me the needed functionality to add a JPEG compressed image to the generated pdf file.

Comment: Would you mind to give us the code snippet of your solution with libHaru?

Answer (score 9):

Actually you can use a UIImageJPEGRepresentation. But there's another step, to then use a JPEG data provider to draw the image:

```
NSData *jpegData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(sourceImage, 0.75);
CGDataProviderRef dp = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)jpegData);
CGImageRef cgImage = CGImageCreateWithJPEGDataProvider(dp, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
[[UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage] drawInRect:drawRect];
```

This worked well for me when drawing to a PDF context.  0.75 compression quality reduced the size of my image-laden PDF by about 75% and it still looked fine.

Comment: Don't forget to release -         CGDataProviderRelease(dp);
        CGImageRelease(cgImage);

Comment: Worked perfectly for me!

Answer (score -1):

If you'd like to compress images you can use [UIImageJPEGRepresentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImageJPEGRepresentation)

```
NSData * UIImageJPEGRepresentation (
   UIImage *image,
   CGFloat compressionQuality
);
```

you could jpeg convert/compress a PNG image with

```
NSData *someImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(pngImage, 0.6); // quality 0.6 (60%) (from 0.0-1.0).
UIImage *newCompressedJPG = [UIImage imageWithData:someImageData];
```

But i don't think so this will reduce your PDF size. Because when you place the UIImage to your pdf the RAW image get's placed (as far as i know).

**Update 1:** 
its compressibility varies from 0.0 to 1.0 (thanks to [Leena](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1045055/leena))

Comment: Thanks for the comment and you are right, when drawing the image into the pdf context the actual RAW image data is drawn. What I need is a way to add the jpeg compressed image - this could possibly need to use something other than quartz and CGPDF.