# Compress an iOS PDF File?

Tags: ios, pdf, compression

I have made an app that can make a PDF file.  I just have one image as the base, and layer text and other images on top of it to make the PDF.  The issue is the PDF is about 9 MB, and just one page.  Is there a way to compress the PDF down so its not so big?

```
- (IBAction)generatePdfButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    pageSize = CGSizeMake(792, 612);
    NSString *fileName = @"Demo.pdf";
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *pdfFileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    [self generatePdfWithFilePath:pdfFileName];
}

- (void) drawText
{
    CGContextRef    currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(currentContext, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

    NSString *textToDraw = @"Text goes here";

    UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:22.0];



    CGRect renderingRect = CGRectMake(160, 177.82, 590, 95);

    [textToDraw drawInRect:renderingRect
                  withFont:font
             lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping
                 alignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];

}

- (void) drawImage
{
    UIImage * demoImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"demo.png"];
    [demoImage drawInRect:CGRectMake( 0, 0, 792, 612)];
}

- (void) generatePdfWithFilePath: (NSString *)thefilePath
{
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(thefilePath, CGRectZero, nil);


    BOOL done = NO;
    do
    {

        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, pageSize.width, pageSize.height), nil);


         [self drawImage];

        [self drawText];


        done = YES;
    }
    while (!done);

    // Close the PDF context and write the contents out.
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

}
```

Comment: just how big are these images? and how many are you putting in there?

Comment: How do you add the image to the PDF? I ran into a similar issue when adding full sized images to the PDF but with a much smaller frame. The PDF still contained the full sized image internally. I had to first scale the image to size, then add the smaller image to the PDF.

Comment: The PDF needs to be 11" x 8.5".  The background image is 11 x 8.5 and is 13 MB.  I tried a smaller version, but the PDF came out blurry when printed.  See Original Question to see code

Comment: How big (width and height in pixels) is demo.png? If it's bigger than 792x612 then you should scale the image (create a new UIImage with the smaller size) and add the smaller UIImage to the PDF.

Comment: It is bigger than 792 x 612 because when I had the smaller 792 x 612 image, it came out blurry in the pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to make a PDF smaller when it contains an image is to use the JPEG representation of that image. The size of the PDF becomes dependent on the degree of compression of the JPEG. I know this not from making a PDF in iOS but from making a PDF in real life.

You might be helped by this question: [Can I use JPEG compression for images in pdf files generated on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10187549/can-i-use-jpeg-compression-for-images-in-pdf-files-generated-on-ios)

Note the use of ImageIO framework so you can set your compression level. You'll need to experiment, of course, to get the best compromise value.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by this.  Do I keep the demo.png in the project, and compress it in the app, and then use THAT image for the PDF?

Answer (score -1):

**pod 'PDFGenerator', '~> 3.1'**
do {

```
            let data = try PDFGenerator.generated(by: images, dpi: .default)
            
            debugPrint("--DataLengh: \(data.count / 1024)")
            
            if let doc = PDFDocument(data: data) {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(doc)
                }
            }
            
        } catch  {
            print("Func_createPdfFrom: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).