# PDF generation in XCode

Tags: ios, pdf-generation

I am a newbie in iPhone development. I am planning to do a PDF application for iPhone. The functionality is:

1. User will type their input in a text field (which is going to be the content of the PDF file).
2. I have to modify the PDF file through code while saving (paragraphs, tables, bullets etc).
3. User can save it in their own name.
4. User can send the PDF file as attachment of MFMailComposer.

So I have searched and got many links. However I didn't find any leading details to create and modify a PDF file in iPhone/iPad.

Can anyone please provide me a good reference to do this. Are there any alternatives to do this?

Comment: Do you need to have the ability to dynamically modify the PDF itself, or do you need to just `create` a PDF with supplied input?

Comment: @skram: I need to dynamically modify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used this reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html

It contains theoretical explanations and source code examples

Answer (score 1):

Please use the below link to download sample apps for **PDF Reader/Viewer in iOS**

[PDF Reader/Viewer in iOS](https://github.com/vfr/Reader)

Also please look at detail about pdf creation, manipulation etc in below links

[developer.apple: PDF Document Creation, Viewing, and Transforming](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html)

[Fast-and-lean-pdf-viewer-for-iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3889634/fast-and-lean-pdf-viewer-for-iphone-ipad-ios-tips-and-hints)

Answer (score 0):

If you were doing a Phonegap app I'd say got for [jsPDF](http://code.google.com/p/jspdf/), which would enable you to create (basic) PDF files in Javascript. I don't do Obj-C, but a quick look on SO provides [good links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362734/ios-sdk-programmatically-generate-a-pdf-file).