# iOS PDF with libHaru issue

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, pdf, libharu

I use [libHary](https://github.com/akisute/iPhonePDF) to create PDF.
I use this answer [iOS SDK - Programmatically generate a PDF file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362734/ios-sdk-programmatically-generate-a-pdf-file) to create pdf.

In this library method HPDF_LoadPngImageFromFile exist, but I need to load image from data (or UIImage). How can I do that?

Now the best solution for me is to right data to png file and then load it, but I thing better solution should exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LibHaru is platform independent so it does not know about about UIImage or NSData.
You have 2 options:
1. Save the UIImage/NSData to a file and then load the image from the file using HPDF_LoadPngImageFromFile method or
 
2. Save the UIImage to a NSData object, get a pointer to the NSData buffer ([nsdataobject bytes] method) and then use HPDF_LoadPngImageFromMem to load the image from memory.