# Generate PDF file in ios

Tags: iphone

Hi in my application I have to generate PDF file. That pdf file may include Images,Description,Numbers,border lines and page numbers.Can any one please let me know how to generate pdf file in ios.

[image]

Comment: refer to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362734/ios-sdk-programmatically-generate-a-pdf-file?rq=1

Comment: This I found already may know is there any instance code available with you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create your custom view to add image, tableview or anything. Points the pdf converter to the mutable data object and to the UIView to be converted to pdf.

Try this:

```
NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData,self.bounds, nil);
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();

    CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // draws rect to the view and thus this is captured by UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData
    [self.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];

    // remove PDF rendering context
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    // Retrieves the document directories from the iOS device
    NSArray* documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);

    NSString* documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* documentDirectoryFilename = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ess.pdf"];

    // instructs the mutable data object to write its context to a file on disk
    [pdfData writeToFile:documentDirectoryFilename atomically:YES];
```

Comment: Hi Thanks I tried it. But here I have one doubt that at this condition If (stringSize.height >= renderingRect.size.height) how can we split the text in two pages? Please can you share this code.

Comment: pageSize = CGSizeMake(612, 792); change and try know

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. Actually I am facing an issue while spliting the text in two pages. I am unable to get any idea how to split the text in two pages. I am setting bottomline by getting text size and bottom line position. I am attaching the screen shot please check this and let me know the solution for this.

Comment: Hi ios developer please check the attchment and help me to resolve my issue.

Comment: @iOSDeveloper Link is Not working Please update...

Comment: Hi pranav, i had update my answer above.