# Is it possible to create PDF forms using UIKit

Tags: ios, ipad, uikit, pdf-generation

For a project I'm working on I have to generate a PDF document containing form fields. Is this possible using UIKit?

Comment: please checkout this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362734/ios-sdk-programmatically-generate-a-pdf-file) too.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. The CoreGraphics API and UIKit do not provide support for creating PDF annotations and form fields.